# Best way to insert date and timestamp into database using java

Tags: java, database

Before finishing off the coding, I would like to know what would be the best way to insert date and time stamp in database using java.

Database could be oracle, mssql, db2 or mysql.

I want to insert date and time stamp in a way so that its retrieval should be easy for reconciliation of records. Lets say our DB admin might want to pull records between range Aug 2015 and Oct 2015 and some time range as well.

**Option 1:** using different sql query scripts for each database type

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (YOUR_DATE_COLUMN, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) 
VALUES (SYSDATE, 1234, 567);
```

**Option 2:** using java syntax as follows

**Example:**

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
long t = date.getTime();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(t);
java.sql.Time sqlTime = new java.sql.Time(t);
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(t);

pstmt.setDate(2, sqlDate);
pstmt.setTime(3, sqlTime);
pstmt.setTimestamp(4, sqlTimestamp);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Would option 2 handle proper insertion of date and timestamp in different db types?

Comment: I think if you want date/time values in a single field/column then `java.sql.Timestamp` would be the preferred method, as the other two will truncate the date base on their individual needs. Of course, this assumes that the database supports the SQL TIMESTAMP type

Comment: @MadProgrammer Single column or separate column, I would like insertion of date and time to be db agnostic. If I am not wrong oracle and db2 supports date type but not sure about time stamp. So do I insert date and time separately or in a single column?

Answer (score 2):

> Would option 2 handle proper insertion of date and timestamp in different db types?

Assuming that you used the right Java types matching the underlying column types, yes that's the idea.

Note that in the example you gave, you set columns 2, 3, 4, but not 1. You will obviously need to set column 1 too, and they should match with columns in the SQL string (you didn't include), with ?  placeholders for the values for the appropriate columns.

In any case, check the documentation of the jdbc drivers of the databases you want to work with, look at the implementation notes concerning the mapping of Java types to SQL types, and any potential documented gotchas.

Comment: Option 2 - It was just a example I copied off site. Yeah I noticed that. pardon me for the trouble.

Comment: Do I use separate column for date and time or single column because different database support date and time differently. For say, oracle date columnn also supports time

Comment: If you want your unit of data to be date + time, then you should use Timestamp and let the driver map it to the right class. Separating date and time to different columns will be troublesome, and not natural if your unit of data is date+time. If that's not your unit, and you need the values independently, then by all means, separate them

Answer (score 1):

Definitely option 2 will handle the insertion properly. At least better than option 1 :-) Of course you should create columns with proper data types in the database.

The things that you should be careful for are:

1. The datatypes in the database;
2. Truncation of the data depending on 1);
3. Time zones (the default time zone of the JVM will be used) so if you need conversions you have to care about this. E.g. @see [setDate(int, Date, Calendar)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date,%20java.util.Calendar%29)

Comment: Do I use separate column for date and time or single column because different database support date and time differently. For say, oracle date columnn also supports time

Comment: At least for oracle and mysql you should be fine with a single column.